# Rotating Array on a daily basis?

Tags: c#

I have an array of five colors that I want to rotate daily in and out of a header. How would I go about doing this syntactically in C#? I can write it in Javascript easily but not in C#.

Comment: Create an array of 5 elements. Use DateTime.Day (or whatever value is appropriate) % 5 to get your index. Choose the color via the index. Done.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the current day of the year as way of rotating the colors.

```
var color = colors[DateTime.Now.DayOfYear % 5];
```

Comment: It's not perfect at the transition from one year to the next, but that's probably fine. You could always do `(DateTime.Today - SomeInitialDate).TotalDays % 5`